# See error codes list in unix with errno -l command

Tags: bash, unix, error-handling, errno

I am using unix and when I type in:

```
man errno
```

I get exlanatory window, that says that I should be able to see all error codes and their meanings like that:

```
 $ errno -l
 EPERM 1 Operation not permitted
 ENOENT 2 No such file or directory
 ESRCH 3 No such process
 EINTR 4 Interrupted system call
 EIO 5 Input/output error
 ...
```

But when I type errno -l, my console says

```
-bash: errno: command not found
```

How can I see all errors list in unix? And how to use example that is provided in man page (man errno)?
Thank you.

Comment: You have to install the program. In most Linux distributions the according package is called `moreutils`. Therefore use `sudo apt install moreutils`, `pacman -S moreutils`, or whatever package manager your system uses.

Comment: Oh, I see. I am afraid I cannot do that because this is my university server

Answer (score 0):

As @Socowi wrote in his comment on your question,

> You have to install the program. In most Linux distributions the according package is called moreutils. Therefore use `sudo apt install moreutils`, `pacman -S moreutils`, or whatever package manager your system uses.

If you do not have sufficient permissions to do this, you can find Michael Mazack's list of error codes (along with a perl script or a C program to print them out) here: http://mazack.org/unix/errno.php (or wayback: https://web.archive.org/web/20220327145507/http://mazack.org/unix/errno.php )